# Volunteer Management Software that does NOT require volunteers to create an account?

Tags: gratis, contact-manager

I'm looking for volunteer management software that allows me to:

- List volunteer contact information
- Organize volunteers by role
- Organize volunteers by availability
- Organize volunteers by *preferred method of contact*
- Create schedules
- Email reminders

Many options I've found cover these bases (although I have been unable to find "organize by preferred method of contact") but require my volunteers sign up/register for the service. I do not want this. I want something that *I* can use to organize my contacts behind the scenes.

For what we need, requiring my volunteers to sign up for and use an application is an unnecessary and, frankly, off-putting burden for them.

These volunteers would not be users. I want to enter and organize their contact information myself.

Is there any software out there that matches these criteria?

Comment: Are these volunteers users or not? Are you entering all the data yourself? You are the only user?

Comment: How system can know volunteer information if not by registration?

Comment: These volunteers would not be users. My volunteers are mostly older individuals who aren't tech savvy. I want to enter and organize their contact information myself.